# AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the Security Context

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-java-config

I get the below error when I try to send JSON payload from POSTMAN plugin of chrome browser to controller exposed as REST URL - http://localhost:8080/services/acc/create

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/services] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext] with root cause
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:339)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:198)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at com.webadvisors.controller.HotelRestController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$e9f80d9.createHotel(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
```

I selected BasicAuth as authorization type and entered username and password while sending JSON payload to REST URL in POSTMAN.

1) Controller class

```
@RestController
public class AccountRestController {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService accountService;

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRATOR')")
    @RequestMapping(value= "/acc/create", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public HotelDTO createHotel(@RequestBody AccountDTO accDTO) throws Exception{
        return accountService.create(accDTO);
    }
}
```

2) Security Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.freelance", scopedProxy = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
        http.httpBasic();
        http.csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
}
```

3) Spring security dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I am sending the authentication credentials in the POSTMAN. But still why am I getting the above exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created a `springSecurityFilterChain` with `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration):

> The first step is to create our Spring Security Java Configuration. The configuration creates a Servlet Filter known as the `springSecurityFilterChain` which is responsible for all the security (protecting the application URLs, validating submitted username and passwords, redirecting to the log in form, etc) within your application.

but you didn't use it (it is not in your stack trace).

You have to register `springSecurityFilterChain`. If you have a Servlet 3.0+ environment, see [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer-with-spring-mvc):

> **AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer with Spring MVC**
>
> If we were using Spring elsewhere in our application we probably already had a `WebApplicationInitializer` that is loading our Spring Configuration. If we use the previous configuration we would get an error. Instead, we should register Spring Security with the existing `ApplicationContext`. For example, if we were using Spring MVC our `SecurityWebApplicationInitializer` would look something like the following:
>
> ```
> import org.springframework.security.web.context.*;
>
> public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer
>   extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
>
> }
> ```
>
> This would simply only register the springSecurityFilterChain Filter for every URL in your application. After that we would ensure that `WebSecurityConfig` was loaded in our existing ApplicationInitializer. For example, if we were using Spring MVC it would be added in the `getRootConfigClasses()`
>
> ```
> public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer extends
>       AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
>
>   @Override
>   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
>       return new Class[] { WebSecurityConfig.class };
>   }
>
>   // ... other overrides ...
> }
> ```