# MethodSecurity with CustomPermissionEvaluator does not work for SpringSecurity

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm struggling with my Spring Security configuration which I wasn't able to make it works so far. need your help.

**This is my configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MethodSecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler =
                new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new CustomPermissionEvaluator());
        return expressionHandler;
    }
}
```

**This is the `CustomPermissionEvaluator`:**

```
public class CustomPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**This is the controller:**

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#test, 'write')")
@PostMapping("/test")
public Result saveTest(@RequestBody Test test) {
    return Result.build();
}
```

Everything looks like OK and simple, but when I request the rest API, got the following exception:

```
.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
```

Anyone can give me any hint on what to do? Thanks~

Comment: did you make use of `@EnableWebSecurity`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710743/authenticationcredentialsnotfoundexception-an-authentication-object-was-not-fou) may help

Comment: The error is reffering to a lack of Authentication object instead of Authorization. Have you defined a UserDetailsService and are you sure your authentication was successful?

Comment: @guleryuz No, I only enabled `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`, because there is no need for web security of my business. is that OK?

Comment: @RoaldBankras yes, I defined a UserDetailsService, but I do not know how to connect with the method security, could you please tell me how to do?

Comment: do you have any authentication in your application?

Comment: Per [this blog](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security/), you can wire your userDetailService by defining a method to get the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. On this builder you can either define a simple `inMemoryAuthentication` for testing, or wire your implementation of the `AuthenticationProvider` or `UserDetailService`.

Comment: @RoaldBankras  thanks for kind help.

Comment: You're welcome. I've rewritten the comments as an answer. Consider accepting the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is refering to a lack of `Authentication` object instead of `Authorization`. Have you defined a `UserDetailsService` and are you sure your authentication was successful?

Per [this blog](https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/04/spring-security-java-config-preview-method-security/), you can wire your userDetailService by defining a method to get the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`. On this builder you can either define a simple `inMemoryAuthentication` for testing, or wire your implementation of the `AuthenticationProvider` or `UserDetailService`.